# Why do I encounter too much recursion on trigger click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net

I have the following code at my C# web application:

```html
<div id="divDocument" class="cursor-pointer">
  <i class="icon-document font-size-3em mt10 fileupload-border"></i>
  <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadDocument" runat="server" CssClass="d-none" />
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#divDocument").click(function () {
    $("#<%= fileUploadDocument.ClientID %>").trigger('click');
  });
});
```

But I'm getting the following error at javascript console:

> InternalError: too much recursion

Can someone help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're raising a click event on a child element of the current element which is having a click event handled, thus creating an infinite loop.

To fix this you either need to remove the inner `trigger('click')`, or add a `stopPropagation()` call on that inner element.

*However* it's worth noting that if your goal is to increase the hit area of the file input, then the better approach is to wrap a `label` element around the `input`. This avoids your problem and removes the need for any JS code.

```html
<label>
  <i class="icon-document font-size-3em mt10 fileupload-border"></i>
  <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadDocument" runat="server" CssClass="d-none" />
</label>
```

Comment: Good point at handling an "XY problem."  ... And you could even wrap something bigger around *that!*

Answer (score 1):

It is because upon a click you trigger a click on the child, which, on its turn triggers a click on its parent, which is the current element, which triggers a click on the child and so on.

You can prevent this from occurring via a label, as Rory McCrossan correctly suggested and that would solve the issue in the case of a click, however, that's a very specific solution and I think a more general solution, which would work even if wrapping a label around the item was not an option, or, if the event would not be a click.

This is how you can achieve that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#divDocument").click(function (event) {
    if ((event.target || event.srcElement).id !== "<%= fileUploadDocument.ClientID %>") $("#<%= fileUploadDocument.ClientID %>").trigger('click');
  });
});
```